# How Can I run EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator (T4) programmatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, templates, t4

I want to use "EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code First Generator" but programmatically not from VS.
[EntityFramework Reverse POCO Code Github](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator)

In fact I want to Run T4 for this purpose from C# code
I downloaded simple-t4-engine for this purpose
[Simple T4 Engine](https://github.com/jakefoster/simple-t4-engine)

I wrote some code like this :

```
        Engine engine = new Engine();
        TemplatingHost host = new TemplatingHost(System.Text.Encoding.UTF32);
        host.IncludeFileSearchPaths.Add(@"D:\IncludeFiles");

        string templateFileName = "some template";
        // NOTE: Doesn't actually seem to care about the name of the template file?  True, but does use the path to search for stuff.
        host.TemplateFile = templateFileName;
        string input = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\IncludeFiles\T4Files\Database.tt");
        string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(input, host);
        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\IncludeFiles\T4Files\Output.txt", output);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (CompilerError error in host.Errors)
        {
           sb.AppendLine(error.ToString());
        }

        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\IncludeFiles\T4Files\ErrorLog.txt", sb.ToString());
```

But I got some errors (Output.txt is Empty)

**ErrorLog.txt :**

```
   error : Running transformation: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast transparent proxy to type 'System.IServiceProvider'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31A64EBEAB614B57E81A1789EC7637709A091834D5CA991E8A2195B15E2A0DFF588B0C98DCEDA8AD6902329A28B09556BDE2A9BEDFA48812CCC12CA1E68AA1C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetDTE()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31A64EBEAB614B57E81A1789EC7637709A091834D5CA991E8A2195B15E2A0DFF588B0C98DCEDA8AD6902329A28B09556BDE2A9BEDFA48812CCC12CA1E68AA1C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetCurrentProject()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31A64EBEAB614B57E81A1789EC7637709A091834D5CA991E8A2195B15E2A0DFF588B0C98DCEDA8AD6902329A28B09556BDE2A9BEDFA48812CCC12CA1E68AA1C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetConfigPaths()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31A64EBEAB614B57E81A1789EC7637709A091834D5CA991E8A2195B15E2A0DFF588B0C98DCEDA8AD6902329A28B09556BDE2A9BEDFA48812CCC12CA1E68AA1C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetConnectionString(String& connectionStringName, String& providerName, String& configFilePath)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31A64EBEAB614B57E81A1789EC7637709A091834D5CA991E8A2195B15E2A0DFF588B0C98DCEDA8AD6902329A28B09556BDE2A9BEDFA48812CCC12CA1E68AA1C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.InitConnectionString()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31A64EBEAB614B57E81A1789EC7637709A091834D5CA991E8A2195B15E2A0DFF588B0C98DCEDA8AD6902329A28B09556BDE2A9BEDFA48812CCC12CA1E68AA1C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetDbProviderFactory()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating31A64EBEAB614B57E81A1789EC7637709A091834D5CA991E8A2195B15E2A0DFF588B0C98DCEDA8AD6902329A28B09556BDE2A9BEDFA48812CCC12CA1E68AA1C9.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()
```

Can anyone help me for solve this problem ? 
or introduce a *better way* for run **Database.tt** in runtime an execute in C# programmatically.

**Database.tt**

- EF.Reverse.POCO.Core.ttinclude
- EF.Reverse.POCO.ttinclude
- EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude
- EF6.Utility.CS.ttinclude
- GenerateTSQL.Utility.ttinclude

Answer (score 6):

I am the author of the Entity Framework Reverse POCO Generator.

Unfortunately, you can't run this outside of Visual Studio because the code depends on it. The EnvDTE provides the ability for the reverse generator to add/remove generated files from the Visual Studio project. Without this, it will not be able to do it's job.

Others have asked if they can run it on the build server. However the build server may not have access to the database it needs to reverse engineer. So always generate the code by saving the tt settings file, and commit the generated code to source control, and from there on to your build server.

By the way, just to be clear: I don't want this project to be automated outside of Visual Studio, or to be included in another product of any kind. This is stipulated in the license.

Comment: while I appreciate the tool I'm confused by your comments regarding licensing.  This is distributed as Apache 2.0, which allows for modification, derivation, distribution, etc.  After a quick review I see no mention of the license limitations, and based on it being Apache 2.0 I see nothing to prevent anyone from removing the blockers for automating this utility.

Comment: ...after researching this (very briefly) it seems that you've released this under both APL 2.0 (via VisualStudioGallery.com) and a modified APL 2.0 (via GitHub).  My sense is that the modified APL 2.0 likely isn't valid--Apache typically doesn't let you change their licenses without fully de-branding (you can't claim it's an apache license after changing it).  Since it's being distributed as stock APL 2.0 via VS Gallery those versions of the plugin clearly allow for modification and redistribution.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I don't think you can claim Apache 2.0.  You modified the license, so it's not an Apache 2 license anymore.

Comment: Hey Simon, just wondering if your position on allowing the usage of EF Reverse POCO Generator outside of the VS environment has changed in the last four years?

With the increased popularity of other IDEs / editors such as Rider or VS Code, is it something you might consider?

Comment: @LiamFlanagan Yes, I plan on creating a version you can run as a dotnet command for EF Core versions. For version 3 I completely re-wrote it as a standard C# project. I've a separate project that takes the code and builds the shipped .ttinclude T4 template. For EF6 is was not possible due to how Visual Studio keeps tabs on the C# files in the project. With .Net Core it's now possible to run it as a dotnet command. I have created https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator/issues/610

Answer (score -1):

You can use [TextTransform Utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126245.aspx) to transform T4 files outside Visual Studio. Normally you can find util in folder:

```
\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\TextTemplating\
```

I think this is a start for your problem please research more about this tool and check if fit your issue.

Comment: the issue is that this T4 file explicitly depends on the DTE environment of Visual Studio.  So while many/most can be easily ran outside of Visual Studio this particular one cannot.